# Error With DataPager and DataGrid/DataForm

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, paging, datapager

Does anyone know what this error means? I get it when I try to page past page 80 if I have more than 161 pages in a DataGrid.

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot Change currency when an item has validation errors or its being edited and AutoCommit is false

Answer (score 0):

Examine the data it's being bound to and see what looks wrong with the numbers on the rows between (80 * Rows per Page) and (81 * Rows per Page)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Data its all basically the same thing just incremented by numbers (ex data1, data2, data3... data2000) I just realized it happens when I try to go more than half way through the data (ex if I have 50 items 10per page and I try to go past page 3 then it throws that error

Comment: So actually yes there was something wrong at page 80... It started repeating the first rows again... So arguably, my answer did kinda point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Its because I was adding my list of data to itself so it had a bunch of duplicate data and it didnt like that.